# Finding % of a nutrient dry matter basis

Tags: percentages

I have a 6 pound recipe with 4 pounds ground beef.  Every 100 grams of ground beef has 1.85 grams of Arginine and 58.8% moisture.  How much % Arginine on a dry matter basis is in my 6 pound recipe that has 4 pounds of this ground beef?

Second part; mg per kg.  I have 28.2 mg per kg of iron per every 100 grams of ground beef.  How do I figure out mg/kg on a dry matter (58.8% moisture), and then how do calculate the mg/kg of this iron on a dry matter basis for my 4 pounds of beef in the same recipe as mentioned?

Comment: How many grams per pound please? In addition, what have you tried?

Comment: Will the moisture evaporate? totally ? and when, before weighing and adding the meet to the recipe, or after upon cooking the recipe (whose other components are dry ?) ?

Comment: I am making dog food and need to match the AAFCO recommendations.  Some nutrients they list as % and other are mg/kg but all have to be on a dry matter basis.  I have found an equation to find dry matter which works for the nutrients shown in a percentage and that is: % of the nutrient/100%-moisture% multiplied by 100.  This gives me the dry matter of a nutrient per 100 grams.  For arginine I tried 1.85% divided by 41.2 which is 4.49% arginine out of 100 grams of beef per 100 grams.  I just cant figure out how to find out how much % is in my actual recipe.  Do I calculate % of a %?

Comment: for the second part, I am unable to find a way to calculate dry matter when the amount is stated in mg/kg instead of as a %.  I searched veterinary books, asked vet nutritionists and still unable to get an answer.  AAFCO states certain nutrients as mg/kg and I need to first find a formula for obtaining the dry matter on a mg/kg then how to calculate how many mg/kg are in my recipe per ingredient amount.

Comment: this is where the aafco profile is http://www.aafco.org/Portals/0/SiteContent/Regulatory/Committees/Pet-Food/Reports/Pet_Food_Report_2013_Midyear-Proposed_Revisions_to_AAFCO_Nutrient_Profiles.pdf